# NodeJs on a Cloud Server

Tags: node.js

Im new to hosting node sites in the cloud and just now I've pulled and ran `npm install` and `bower install` on my project on a cloud server.

I've navigated to the directory my node `app.js` is in and ran `node app.js` and the return is

> Express server listening on 9000, in development mode

so how do I get to view this in the browser? when I navigate to the server IP with the port number appending it I get

> This site can’t be reached

Comment: Is the port open in the firewall (iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 9000 -j ACCEPT)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably because the port is not open from the cloud side. I have never had to open the port from the OS side for node server, unless you have specially setup a firewall to do so.

If you're using Azure VM, go in the "Endpoints" section and add the port to open.